# Grunt : Append lines in whole file. In beginning and ending of a file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have to add lines to file abc.js

```
myfunction.init = function(){
Code of abc.js file goes here
}
```

I have to add '`myfunction.init = function(){`' and '`}`' before and after the abc.js file respectively.
Are we having any plugging for this kind of work.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) has a `banner` and a `footer`config option; you could put these lines of code in there for a simple solution.

-OR- 
you could do something like this with grunt-contrib-concat:

```
compile_js: {
    src: [
        '<%= vendor_files.js %>',
        'module.prefix',
        '<%= build_dir %>/src/**/*.js',
        'module.suffix'
    ],
    dest: '<%= compile_dir %>/assets/<%= pkg.name %>-<%= pkg.version %>.js'
}
```